# Importing Swift file to Obj-C File

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to access a few Swift files in my project from an Obj-C .m file. The project I'm working on is in Swift 2.2 on Xcode 7.3.1 and has the necessary file below.

```
"MyProductName-Swift.h"
```

The problem is, when I create a new Swift file, it is not getting added to the "MyProductName-Swift.h" file. I have also deleted the Derived Data folder and cleaned my project.

I have gone over some other articles already, including the ones below.

[Importing Swift into Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910217/importing-swift-into-objective-c)

[Importing Project-Swift.h into a Objective-C class...file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328034/importing-project-swift-h-into-a-objective-c-class-file-not-found)

[How to import Swift code to Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c)

Comment: Did you also check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c ?

Comment: Yes I did, thanks! Will edit to include.

Comment: Did you write @objc before class declaration in Swift file ?

Comment: Yes I did..interestingly the classes that are showing up correctly in the Project-Swift.h file do not have @objc before the class declaration.

Comment: you are creating swift file in your project or you are dragging swift file in your project ?

Comment: I have done both and neither worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to me not being used to adding .swift files manually to the Compile Sources in Build Phases. Once I added the files where they needed to be it was resolved.